# Xamarin.Forms - Display all items without scrolling

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im using a scrollview to display my homepage, it contains many controls, including 2 CollectionViews, my problem is that when the user is scrolling down the home page, and once the CollectionView is reached, he will get stuck in the CollectionView's scroller, i want all the items (about 40 items) shown in the CollectionView without the  scroller so that the  user can keep scrolling the homepage and through the CollectionView's items towards the controls bellow.
I have tried to set a fixed height for the CollectionView but that didnt work.
Also, i found an article talking about using a BindableLayout, but i read somewhere that it can be much slower than CollectionView and it doesnt support the item layout (im using span="2" to show 2 items next to each other on each row)

Comment: jpg speaks thousands of words.

Comment: @Shaw, i included an image

Comment: You could set the `Scroll Orientation` of CollectionView as Horizontal so that there will no scroll issue when user scroll to the CollectionView .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, i couldnt find a way to accomplish this in XAML

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, i actually cannot do that because i need a vertical items layout with a span of 2

Comment: If so in your case using  BindableLayout is a better workaround .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, is there a way to use span="2" with a bindable layout ? i tried but iti didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use BindableLayout of **FlexLayout** . Check the following code

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">

        //.. other elements
 
        <FlexLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding XXX}" Direction="Row"
                AlignItems="Start" Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="SpaceAround" AlignContent="SpaceAround" >
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                   //replace it with your data template
                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="180" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="10"  >

                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Green" /> 

                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

#### Note:

In this way you need to set the width of each item less than half of the width of screen . Otherwise the item will warp to the next row .

[image]

Comment: I had some trouble setting my own layout using BindableLayout + FlexLayout, and i noticed some lag, so my client decided to go with Syncfusion's ListView instead

Comment: That's great ! Happy coding :)